# C# Video Tutorials

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

I am a experienced PHP developer and planning to learn `C#` for developing desktop apps. Being unfamiliar with `C#` and desktop languages I couldnt find a good *Video* tutorial, and Visual C# different then C#?

Can anyone please link me to good Video Series for learning C#

Comment: there is nothing called `visual C#` it is just `C#`

Comment: are you interested in windows forms applications (desktop) or web applications (ASP.NET) ?

Comment: I am interested in developing Desktop Applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some good C# tutorials [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from msdn.

Also Microsoft has some videos [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb798022) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb798022

**NOTE:** If you know Java by any chance, you might be wasting your time on video tutorials, C# is so similar to Java and you can pick it up by experience during the project you are working on. The [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx) is very helpful and similar to Java API.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn to develop desktop applications in C# then there are two obvious directions to go...

Windows Forms video tutorials: http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx

WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) video tutorials: http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx

Windows Forms is the "old school" framework for quickly setting up user interfaces for Windows desktops.  WPF is the newer framework that allows for more flexibility and modularity with your code.

C# is just one of the languages offered by Microsoft to generate .NET code.  Some of the videos will feature heavy use of C# whereas others might feature VB (Visual Basic) or even XAML (a declarative language used in WPF).

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Once I watched these video series. There are 35 videos about C#. Some of them are really relative with desktop application. http://www.quack-ware.com/tutorials/CSharp.aspx?page=1

Answer (score 1):

Pluralsight has a good training program with a free trial period:  http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/Index

Comment: This is great way to learn the ins and outs of .net

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Channel 9 has a lot of great videos. It is really about .Net in general, but has a lot of great stuff on C#. http://channel9.msdn.com/

Comment: I thought `.NET` & `C#` are used together, Please guide me what is a good and easy development language?

Comment: It is C#.NET , they are together.

Comment: There are several other languages in the .Net Platform (VB.Net, F#.Net, and others)